# How to execute same SP in 2 different connection

Tags: sql-server

How to execute same SP in 2 different connection.

Ex: ALTER PROCEDURE test
    ...
    ....

I want to execute this SP in db called "database1" in 192.168.1.100 and same in 192.168.1.102.

I want this to be done using script not using the change connection window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SQLCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) to run a .sql file against multiple server connections.

```
sqlcmd -S <ComputerName>\<InstanceName> -i <MyScript.sql> -d <database_name> -T
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=5) using one of its features called "Run one script on multiple databases".

Editing this to add that this is a tiny and free add-in to SQL Server, that you would find extremely useful.

Comment: I think the question poster wants to run the same script across different "server" connections as opposed to different databases on the same connection. I'm no expert on SSMS Tools Pack but the documentation states "Run selected or full window text on selected databases on the currently connected server. "